# Yii2 Query with multiple tables

Tags: mysql, yii2

**users**

```
ID | customerID | <others>
```

**userTemplates**

```
ID | userID | productCode
```

**templates**

```
ID | customerID | productCode | <others>
```

Im trying to find a nice solution to get all templates that are assigned to a given user based on the **prodCode** in the **userTemplates** table.

The product codes need to contain a wild card % so would be like this P.0100.% or %.0100.%

I have done this so far:

```
$usersTemplates = ArrayHelper::map(userTemplates::find()->where("userID = ".Yii::$app->user->identity->ID."")->all(),'ID','productCode');

$templates = new Query;
$templates->from('templates')
          ->where("customerID = ".Yii::$app->user->identity->customer->ID."")
          ->andWhere("disabled = 0")
          ->andWhere("approved = 1");

foreach($usersTemplates as $prodCode){
    $templates->andWhere("productCode LIKE '%".$prodCode."%'");
}
```

but i end up with this

```
SELECT * FROM `templates` WHERE ((((customerID = 1) AND (disabled = 0)) AND (approved = 1)) AND (productCode LIKE '%TESTWP%')) AND (productCode LIKE '%P.0100.0001%')
```

which is almost there but this bit:

```
AND (productCode LIKE '%TESTWP%')) AND (productCode LIKE '%P.0100.0001%')
```

needs to be:

```
AND ((productCode LIKE '%TESTWP%')) OR (productCode LIKE '%P.0100.0001%'))
```

Im sure there might be a better way of getting the list of templates.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you have a complex query  a simple solution is based on  findBySql

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
  FROM `templates` 
  WHERE ((((customerID = 1) 
  AND (disabled = 0)) 
  AND (approved = 1)) 
  AND ((productCode LIKE '%TESTWP%')) 
  OR (productCode LIKE '%P.0100.0001%'))";

$model = Templates::findBySql($sql)->all();
```